# SSIS package remote execution

Tags: ssis, ssas

I have a Client, running on Server A, which executes a SSIS package which is located on Server B. This SSIS package process a SSAS Tabular Cube which is located on Server C.
The connection from A to B works fine. However, the connection from B to C fails with the error "A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running". The Connection from B to C is via Windows Authentication, the Servver is running and permissions are fine.

When I execute the deployed SSIS package directly on Server B then it works.
When I execute the deployed SSIS package over SSMS on Server A  then doesn't work.
The user is the same on every server on which the services are running.

Comment: My guess would be that you have a "double hop kerberos" issue (extremely searchable term). The account on B can talk directly to C but when asked to relay A's credentials along, it is not trusted for that activity and thus it fails.

Comment: @billinkc Thanks, that was the case. I hadn't thought of that because I searched the error with the SSAS.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Feel free to self-answer below and eventually there'll be a large enough corpus for the search engines to help future people with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a "double hop kerberos" issue. I solved it by creating a SQl Server Agent Job which executes the SSIS Package. The client then starts the Agent Job.

Thanks @billinkc for the comment.